# ping gateway but not domain

Tags: centos, network-interface

I can ping gateway its ok but when I try `ping google.com`
response is; "unknown host google.com"

network-scripts/ifcfg-ens0p3 file content:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="192.168.0.14"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
GATEWAY="192.168.0.1"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="2a523b6c-a995-4522-8030-6131638534d6"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

and /etc/resolve.conf file:

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Also, is that really your `resolv.conf` because that's not the right format for that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `ping 8.8.8.8` then the problem is likely entirely in the format of your `resolv.conf` which should be

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The `DNS1=` and `DNS2=` lines would be what you put in your `ifcg-` file to get it to populate `resolv.conf` correctly

Comment: Adding anything to `resolv.conf` is kind of a bad strategy these days.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the router (gateway) doesn't allow you to talk to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4. It might not forward traffic at all, it might not NAT it properly (you have an rfc 1918 address, so your traffic needs to be natted) or it might have firewall rules not permitting that traffic. (and there's possibly explanations I didn't think of.)